# I need help for adding individual schedules in my Tuya Weekly Schedule (PHP cURL)

Tags: php, php-curl, tuya

I am working on a web site where users can control their thermostat, but I'm having difficulty with the schedule part. I can display it, but when I create a new schedule the temperature desired is not applied, but works in postman. Here's my code:

**Script.php**

```php
class ConnectTuya
{
    private $_baseUrl;
    private $_deviceId;
    private $_clientId;
    private $_secret_key;
    private $_getToken;
    private $_fDevices;
    private $_aDevices;
    private $_bDevices;
    private $_t;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_baseUrl = 'https://openapi.tuyaeu.com/';
        $this->_clientId  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
        $this->_secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $this->_getToken = "v1.0/token?grant_type=1";
        $this->_t = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $this->_fDevices = 'v1.0/iot-03/devices/';
        $this->_aDevices = 'v1.0/devices/';
        $this->_bDevices = 'v2.0/cloud/timer/device/';
    }

    public function get_token()
    {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: '.$this->_clientId,
            't: '.$this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token:'
        );
        $url =  $this->_baseUrl . $this->_getToken;
        $sign = $this->build_sign('GET', $url, [], []);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
    public function get_specification($device_id,  $access_token)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: '.$this->_clientId,
            't: '.$this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'GET';
        $payload = array(
            'device_id' => $device_id
        );
        $url =  $this->_baseUrl . $this->_fDevices . $device_id . '/specification';
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, [], [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    public function send_commands($device_id, $commands ,$access_token)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: '.$this->_clientId,
            't: '.$this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'POST';
        if (empty($commands)) {
            return false;
        }
        $payload = array(
            "commands" => $commands
        );
        $url =  $this->_baseUrl . $this->_fDevices . $device_id . '/commands';
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, $payload, [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    public function get_scheduled($device_id,  $access_token)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: '.$this->_clientId,
            't: '.$this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'GET';
        $payload = array(
            'device_id' => $device_id
        );
        $url =  $this->_baseUrl . $this->_bDevices . $device_id ;
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, [], [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    public function add_scheduled($device_id,$temp_add, $time, $loops, $access_token) {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: ' . $this->_clientId,
            't: ' . $this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
    
        $method = 'POST';
        
        $payload = array(
            "alias_name" => "Scheduled",
            "category" => "Scheduled",
            "time" => $time,
            "timezone_id" => "Europe/Paris",
            "loops" => $loops,
            "functions" => array(
                array(
                    "code" => "switch_1",
                    "value" => true
                ),
                array(
                    "code" => "temp_set",
                    "value" => array("Value" =>strval($temp_add))
                ),
                array(
                    "code" => "customize_mode_switch",
                    "value" => true
                )
            )
        );
        
        $url =  $this->_baseUrl . $this->_bDevices . $device_id;
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, $payload, [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
    
    
    
    

    public function get_device_information($device_id,  $access_token)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: '.$this->_clientId,
            't: '.$this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'GET';
        $payload = array(
            'device_id' => $device_id
        );
        $url =  $this->_baseUrl . $this->_aDevices . $device_id . '/';
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, [], [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    public function delete_scheduled($device_id, $timer_id, $access_token) {
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: ' . $this->_clientId,
            't: ' . $this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'DELETE';

        $url = $this->_baseUrl . $this->_bDevices . $device_id . '/batch?timer_ids=' . $timer_id;
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, [], [], $access_token);
    
        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));
    
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    public function modeVacance($device_id,$access_token, $idVacance, $mode){
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: ' . $this->_clientId,
            't: ' . $this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'PUT';
        $payload = array(
            "timer_id" => $idVacance,
            "enable" => $mode
        );
        $url = $this->_baseUrl . $this->_bDevices . $device_id . '/state';
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, $payload, [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
    public function modeVacanceOther($device_id,$access_token, $idVacance, $mode){
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: ' . $this->_clientId,
            't: ' . $this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
        $method = 'PUT';
        $payload = array(
            "timer_id" => $idVacance,
            "enable" => $mode
        );
        $url = $this->_baseUrl . $this->_bDevices . $device_id . '/state';
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, $payload, [], $access_token);

        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
    public function add_scheduled_Vacence($device_id,$access_token){
        $headers = array(
            'sign_method: HMAC-SHA256',
            'client_id: ' . $this->_clientId,
            't: ' . $this->_t,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'access_token: ' . $access_token
        );
    
        $method = 'POST';
    
        $payload = array(
            "alias_name" => "Scheduled-Vacance",
            "category" => "Scheduled-Vacance",
            "time" => "00:00",
            "timezone_id" => "Europe/Paris",
            "loops" => "1111111",
            "functions" => array(
                array(
                    "code" => "switch_1",
                    "value" => true
                ),
                array(
                    "code" => "temp_set",
                    "value" => 120
                ),
                array(
                    "code" => "customize_mode_switch",
                    "value" => true
                )
            )
        );
    
        $url = $this->_baseUrl . $this->_bDevices . $device_id;
        $sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, $payload, [], $access_token);
    
        $headers[] = "sign: " . $sign;
    
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));
    
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
        curl_close($curl);
    
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    private function build_sign($method, $url ,$payload, $headers, $token = "")
    {
        $str_header = "";
        if ($headers) {
            $str_header = implode("\n", $headers);
        }
        $str_payload = "";
        if ($payload) {
            $str_payload = json_encode($payload);
        }

        $content_SHA256 = hash('sha256', $str_payload);
        
        $parse_url = parse_url($url);
        $part_url = empty($parse_url['path']) ? "" : $parse_url['path'];
        $query_url = empty($parse_url['query']) ? "" : "?" . $parse_url['query'];
        $str_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $content_SHA256 . "\n" . $str_header . "\n" . $part_url . $query_url;

        $sign = strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', $this->_clientId . $token . $this->_t . $str_to_sign, $this->_secret_key));
        return $sign;
    }


}
$ConnexionTuya = new ConnectTuya();
```

The `add_scheduled` function is my only big problem

**index.php**

```
     if(isset ($_POST['time_add']) && isset ($_POST['day_add']) && isset ($_POST['temp_add'])){
            $time_add = $_POST['time_add'];
            $loops_add = $_POST['day_add'];
            $temp_add = $_POST['temp_add'];

            $time_add = strval($time_add);
            $loops_add = strval($loops_add);

            $add_schedule = $ConnexionTuya->add_scheduled($device_id,$temp_add, $time_add, $loops_add, $access_token['result']['access_token']);
            print_r($add_schedule);
        }
```

For the error I got it's when I do it in postman :

```
{
            "alias_name": "Scheduled",
            "category": "Scheduled",
            "date": "00000000",
            "enable": true,
            "functions": [
                {
                    "code": "switch_1",
                    "value": true
                },
                {
                    "code": "temp_set",
                    "value": {
                        "Value": "160.0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "code": "customize_mode_switch",
                    "value": true
                }
            ],
            "loops": "0100000",
            "time": "08:00",
            "timer_id": "320383673",
            "timezone_id": "Europe/Paris"
        }
```

and if i do it in my web site :

```
{
            "alias_name": "Scheduled",
            "category": "Scheduled",
            "date": "00000000",
            "enable": true,
            "functions": [
                {
                    "code": "switch_1",
                    "value": true
                },
                {
                    "code": "temp_set",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "160.0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "code": "customize_mode_switch",
                    "value": true
                }
            ],
            "loops": "0100000",
            "time": "12:48",
            "timer_id": "320385032",
            "timezone_id": "Europe/Paris"
        }
```

The issue is that when I execute my `add_schedule` function, it succeeds, but the result in the `temp_set` code sets the value as `value:temp`. For it to function properly, I require the value to be `Value:temp`.

I try using all I know and the GitHub of the script:
https://github.com/hao159/tuya-connect-php

In postman:

[image: postman]

The web site:

[image: website]

Postman what is working and not working :
[image: postmanValue]

Info in the web site:
[image: web site info]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: "unable to" and "not working" are not meaningful problem descriptions, sorry. We need more detail -especially because we cannot run the code ourselves. Have you done any debugging? What specifically goes wrong with the code, and whereabouts does it start to deviate from what you expected it to do? Do you get an errors? Unexpected output or results? Does the code take a path you didn't expect? Or maybe variables get values you didn't expect and you don't know why? Please be specific - we're expecting that youv'e tried to debug this line by line, and can report on that.

Comment: Also you mention that you can achieve this using postman...so maybe you should show us what you did there, for comparison. Then we can see if there are any obvious differences. Without that, and without any meaningful information about what the code is currently doing when you run it, we are going to simply have to start guessing - which is rarely a good use of anyone's time. You can [edit] your post when you are ready. Thanks.

Comment: In the Postman screenshot, you have a field `loops` which is a string.  In the code you've shown as `index.php` which you said is the problem area, you have a `$loops` variable which presumably corresponds to that field in Postman.  But in the code, you first set it to a string, similar to the one in Postman, and then immediately overwrite it and set it as an array.  That doesn't look right.

Comment: OK, so you edited that code out and replace it with something else, but you haven't told us anything about it - was the previous version *not* your actual code? Are you still getting the same error with this new code?

Comment: I encounter the same error, but the loops are now fixed. The error is related to an invalid sign, and it stems from the combination of ($method, $url, $payload, $headers, $token). I suspect that the payload is the cause of the error.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a problem of scheduling or of calling the API?

Comment: The issue is that when I execute my add_schedule function, it succeeds, but the result in the temp_set code sets the value as value:temp. For it to function properly, I require the value to be Value:temp.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it.

Comment: `For it to function properly, I require the value to be Value:temp.`...so you're saying that your device accepts `"value": { "Value": "160.0" }` as input but not `"value": { "value": "160.0" }`? N.B. Your postman screenshot doesn't seem to reflect the JSON structure you're sending from the PHP, or the samples you've provided. Also the JSON examples don't entirely seem to match the payload created in your add_scheduled function. It's all very inconsistent, leading to ambiguity. And there's tons of irrelevant code cluttering it up, making it harder to see imporant things in what you've posted.

Comment: If we actually take the  `$payload` you've shown in your `add_scheduled` function and json_encode it, we get the `"value":{"Value":"160"}` value that you say you want, with the capital `V`. So what exactly is the problem? It seems the code should  send what you want. Where/how exactly did you see that it wasn't doing that? Is the code you've shown us definitely the code you're actually executing? Go back through _carefully_ and ensure you're really showing us a [mre] of the issue, with all the data/code/details correct and consistent, and anything irrelevant removed. Thanks.

Comment: I am going to edit and provide an image, but when it's curl_extc, for some reason, the value changes from {"Value":"160.0"} to {"value":"160.0"}. However, the API requires the "V" to be capitalized ("Value") to function properly.

Comment: cURL doesn't change the value of the JSON, as far as I know. And as I demonstrated, the JSON which would be produced by the code you've provided would already have the `V` capitalised. How and where _exactly_ have you observed this lower-case `v` happening in your PHP/curl code?

Comment: P.S. Thanks for adding info, but again please also go back through and _remove_ anything which is no longer correct or relevant to this issue. Your question is getting very big and cluttered and confusing for what is actually quite a small problem. And as I said, there is quite a bit of inconsistency apparent in the data and code samples, which needs careful review.

Comment: I don't know where it changes that, and it must be something coming from the Tuya API. I observed the change via Postman.

Comment: `I observed the change via Postman`...then it's even more unclear. Postman has nothing to do with what your cURL code is doing. cURL makes its own request to the API. Are you saying you used Postman to ask the API to retrieve some stored data which was sent by cURL? But if so, then what format you get back the JSON from in a response to a separate request is likely to have no direct relationship to what was sent by cURL. But I don't  really know because you aren't being specific enough about what you did or what you mean. Try to remember we can't see your screen.

Comment: No, I use Postman just to see if it does the right thing or for testing before adding it to the PHP script.

Comment: Your last postman screenshot is of a GET though? So that's retrieving data from the API? So that shows you what's stored in the device, but it doesn't _necessarily_ prove anything about what was sent from PHP, certainly not in terms of small details such as the capitalisation of property names.

Comment: Re your latest picture. That's what you're getting back from the API, but it doesn't prove anything about what was _sent_. As we can see in this demo: https://3v4l.org/9L5GE , encoding the `$payload` shown in your `add_scheduled` code as JSON keeps the capital `V`, and that's what will be sent to the server. So maybe the API somehow misinterprets it, it's unclear.

Comment: The only other thing I'd say though is that the Postman screenshot of your POST request shows the JSON structure `{"code":"temp_set","value":160 }`, whereas in your cURL request you're sending `{"code":"temp_set","value":{"Value":"160.0"}}`. Surely you should also be sending `{"code":"temp_set","value":160 }` in the PHP/cURL, to match what is sent in the Postman  version? Like this: https://3v4l.org/Jc47K

Answer (score -1):

If you check the `send_commands()` method, you can see that it passes the `$payload` to `build_sign()` as an array, not `json_encode()`d.

If you trace through `build_sign()`, you can see it `json_encode()`s the payload it receives.

But if you compare that to `add_scheduled()` - which I understand is the method that is not working - you are passing `build_sign()` an already `json_encode()`d payload.  `build_sign()` will `json_encode()` that a second time, and I guess that is a problem.

Try passing the payload as the original array:

```
// Construct the signature
$sign = $this->build_sign($method, $url, $payload, $headers, $access_token);
```

Comment: did them, but it's not working. It keeps telling me that the sign is invalid, and I also got an additional error, which is:
Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Stage API\modele\ConnectTuya.php on line 234

the line 234 :
curl_setopt_array(...)

Comment: I guess you changed something else, not just what I suggested, because there is no `curl_setopt_array()` in `build_sign()`, and the change I suggested only affects `build_sign()`.  So what did you change?

Comment: The change I made is in "add-schedule," and now I altered it in "build sign," but it disrupted my other function, "send_commands," so that's not it.

Comment: I think there is some miscommunication.  The change I suggested will not affect any of the 7 `curl_setopt_array()` statements in your code, so it is *not* the reason for your new error.  Also, I did not suggest any change in `build_sign()`.  So - it sounds like a) you maybe did not do the change I suggested?  And b) you definitely did do some *other* changes, which I didn't suggest, and which I can't see, so can't help you debug.